# Remove user from a group belonging to another AD

Tags: powershell

We have 3 Domains connected through a trust, and I need to remove a user from multiple groups, including some that are in those other Domains.

I can see all groups through the command:

```
(Get-ADGroup -Server $Domain -Filter *).SamAccountName
```

Receiving this information in a variable, where I make a FOREACH, to use in each group, the command:

```
Remove-ADGroupMember -Server $Domain -Identity "$group" -Members $User  -Confirm:$false -Credential $Credential
```

But this does not work for when I need to remove a user who belongs to another domain.

I tried to pass the user with parameters like:

- B\User
- User ObjectGUID
- User SID

But it does not work.

How do I remove a user belonging to domain B from a domain group A?
Remembering that there is a relationship of trust between them.

Comment: Is $Domain actually changing corresponding to the domain each account is in? You would need to have three different Domain Controllers.

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Is it a permissions issue? (i.e. you need 3 sets of credentials for the 3 domains) as @JacobColvin says, is it a `$domain` issue, where you need to connect to 3 different domain controllers?

Comment: The domain changes where the group is, since I can not see the groups of other domains in the user's "member of".

I put an administrator credential for each domain. The error, which shows, is that the user object does not exist in the domain, which is true, since it is in another domain.

My question is how to do in Powershell, the removal of the user, just as I can do through the graphical interface.